# odd error in sql syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

I have a few lines of code that should make a report about the coupons in OpenCart 1.4.9, but I can't get over this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
 'order where coupon_id = 16' at line 1.
```

```
$getcouponinfo1 = mysql_query("select * from order where coupon_id = $coupon_id")
      or die(mysql_error());
```

The rest of the code can be found [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=26938&p=240287&hilit=coupon+report#p240287).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`order` is a keyword in SQL, you need to quote that table name.

```
select * from `order` where ...
```

Comment: take a look at this link. there are some reserved words in the sql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html so you need to follow @Mat's answer

Answer (score 2):

"order" IS A MySQL reserved word... If you need to call your table "order" then you need to enclose it in backticks (`) in your sql queries.

Your error message is not related to the query that you originally posted (prior to editing your question), but to this query:

```
select * from order where coupon_id = $coupon_id
```

and to the following query where you sum the value of the order

Comment: (OP didn't post any query at all, I edited it in and messed up the first copy/paste)

Comment: Apologies to OP then, and it's the correct query now, so no harm done

Answer (score 2):

`order` is a reserved keyword.

You should use `` `order` `` instead.

Comment: backticks (`) not double quotes (")

Comment: @MarkBaker I know i but the backticks are reserved in SO to highlight the text.It would simply highlight it. I tried it first but couldn't find a way to escape it correctly....

Comment: @SergeyBenner: you can put backticks, but it's a bit convoluted (see my edit)

Answer (score -1):

Because `order` is a reserved word, it is not a good name for a table

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi so, it's better to vote delete this answer, not edit it making whole question active, polluting the list?